# If we know a mod b, and a mod c, how do we determine a mod bc?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In this problem, only b and c are given to us. a is an unknown.

Comment: This is not always solvable, but investigate the Chinese Remainder Theorem, which would apply here if $b$ and $c$ were coprime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a \equiv \beta \mod b$ and $a \equiv \gamma \mod c$ means $a = \beta + m b = \gamma + n c$ for some integers $m,n$.  Then
$\gamma - \beta =  m b - n c$ for some integers $m,n$.  Solve this, if possible, for $m$ and $n$ using the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).